# Query SharePoint List by multiple item IDs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, development, caml-query, splistitem

I have a requirement to query SharePoint list items by multiple ids. I have a collection of list item ids and I want to get the list item collection programmatically.
Is there anyway to do through C# code?

Comment: Could you add SharePoint version to your question, please? Also it is unclear whether you are asking about being able to query passing multiple parameters in one go and getting list items matching the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a concept of `IN Query` in Sharepoint where you can use CAMl to hit with multiple conditions . Below is a code snippet where I've used it to create IN query for 1000 ID's.

```
                SPQuery queryEpisodeDocs = new SPQuery();
                if (count > 500) //count is the number of ID's you have
                {
                    queryEpisodeDocs.Query = @"<Where><Or><In><FieldRef Name='EpisodeID'/><Values>";
                }
                else
                    queryEpisodeDocs.Query = @"<Where><In><FieldRef Name='EpisodeID'/><Values>";


                #region TG in query

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    strEpisodeID = episodeItemcollection[i]["ID"].ToString(); //Here you'll get the ID from the array of ID you have
                    if (i % 500 == 0 && i > 0)
                    {
                        //implement it for more than 500 items

                        queryEpisodeDocs.Query += "</Values></In><In><FieldRef Name='EpisodeID'/><Values>";
                        queryEpisodeDocs.Query += "<Value Type='Text'>" + strEpisodeID + @"</Value>";


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        queryEpisodeDocs.Query += "<Value Type='Text'>" + strEpisodeID + @"</Value>";
                    }

                }
                if (episodeItemcollection.Count > 500)
                {
                    queryEpisodeDocs.Query += "</Values></In></Or></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EpisodeID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
                }
                else
                    queryEpisodeDocs.Query += "</Values></In></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EpisodeID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";

                #endregion
```

You change Fieldref accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CAML as a query language to tell the query which items you want get.
Have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2
In the first example you can modify the **camlQuery.ViewXml** to fit multiple IDs. By doing that you will get a collection of listitems